# Distinct Substring Count. Substrings can only be retrieved by removing from either beginning or the end of string

Tags: string, algorithm

I recently encountered the following problem. I have a solution, but does not work for very large input.

Distinct Substring Count. Substrings can only be retrieved by removing characters from either beginning or the end of string

For example

If given string is abcde, then distinct substrings are by removing characters either from beginning or end 
abcde
abcd
abc
ab
a
bcde
bcd
bc
b
cde
cd
c
de
d
e

My solution keeps each character from beginning as an anchor point and produces different substrings by removing from the end. As I do that, I also use a C# Dictionary data structure, which is basically a HashMap in order to spot duplicates. Algorithm works fine for most good size input, but I was given some input that made C# Dictionary go out of memory. Does anybody have any idea how to make this algorithm work for very large input?

Comment: Assuming a normal meaning of "distinct", the only way you can get a duplicate is if some prefix of the string is identical to the suffix of the same length. So there is no point using a dictionary. You could just go through all the suffixes, comparing each one with the start of the string. That's worst case O(n²), so you want to optimise in the case that the string is a repetition. As a first approximation, try proving the following assertion: if a prefix of string is identical to a suffix of the same string, and that prefix overlaps the suffix, the string is a repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Suffix Array to solve it.
Let string "abcde"
then your Suffix Array might be
0, 1, 2, 3, 4 which stands for(abcde, bcde, cde, de, e)

You will also need (length of) Longest Common Prefix between adjacent suffixes.

Your answer should be L * (L+1) / 2 - sum(LCP)

Memory Complexity is O(N), and TIme Complexity if O(N log N). I won't explain how to get Suffix Array and LCP, because it is too long to explain. You can search it elsewhere.

If this is too hard, you can use dictionary that you used, but put hashed value instead of full substring. But this is not accurate solution. You can Use solution I wrote above for accurate result.

Comment: In my question, substrings can only be retrieved in a certain way. You suggest to use the Suffix Array with binary Search to find if certain substring already exists or not?

Comment: Do you know Suffix Array?

Comment: Once you get suffix array and LCP, what do you do with them to solve this problem?